# How to validate an XSD (schema document)?

Tags: ide, xsd

I want to validate XSD (schema document) created by my application. I want to find whether the generated XSD has any validation errors

Answer (score 2):

What's your setup? Most IDEs can validate XML (Eclipse, Intellij IDEA etc). There are [online checkers](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv) available, and you can of course do it programmatically as well.

Answer (score 1):

Validate it against the XSD schema:

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd